# Linq with null parameters not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I don't understand why this query is not working, can you please help me?

```
 public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> MyList(int? id, string name="")
{
 var list =db.Entity
    .Where(p=>
          (name==null? p.Name !=null : p.Name==name) && 
          (id.hasValue || p.Id==id)
    .Select(n=>new SelectListItem()
          {
           Text=n.Name,
           Value=n.Id.ToString()
          }).ToList();
return list;
}
```

I want to have the full list when both parameters are null!! but I get an empty list when both parameters are null.

The snippet code is from a big method which contain several query like this one.

Comment: You probably mean `(!id.HasValue || p.Id == id)`

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you're testing with both parameters `null`? It's suspicious that you would set the default value for `name` to an empty string, which almost certainly won't match any record.

Comment: I think it should be `id.hasValue && p.Id==id`

Comment: @Shaharyar The OP asks to not filter on `id` when `id == null` (or equivalently `!id.HasValue` as in Rhumborl's comment).

Comment: Also you should check `String.IsNullOrEmpty` because here you assign an empty value to `name` which is not equal to `null` obviously. @hvd yeah little misunderstood the scenario.

Comment: @Shaharyar I suspect `String.IsNullOrEmpty` won't be recognised by Entity Framework, and won't be translated to SQL, meaning it just gives an exception instead.

Comment: Never tried it, but its the first condition of ternary so I think it will be compiled as C# and won't be converted to SQL. I mean it like: `String.IsNullOrEmpty(name) ? p.Name != null : p.Name == name`.

Comment: @Shaharyar That's not how EF works. EF either translates to SQL, or throws an exception, for anything that's part of the query, and it is included in the query here.

Comment: @hvd Lack of knowledge, thanks for correcting it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you do not want to perform filtering when the value is `null`. Then you should write:

```
.Where(p=>
          (name == null || p.Name == name) && 
          (id == null || p.Id == id)
```

And you should change the signature of the function to set the default value for parameter `name` to `null` rather than empty string.

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> MyList(int? id, string name = null)
```

Answer (score 5):

Per the comments, there are two problems:

Firstly, your condition for `id` isn't quite right. Secondly, your default argument for `name` is an empty string, not `null`.

However, there is room for more improvements: by embedding your `name == null` (and same for `id`) in the query, your query will be constructed in a way that translates the `null` check to SQL. That's good if there's a chance of `name` changing its value after the query has constructed, but there's no chance of that happening here. You can instead dynamically construct your query:

I commented out the `p.Name != null` check. If your names are possibly `null`, then according to the question, you don't want them filtered out when `name == null`.

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> MyList(int? id, string name=null)
{
  IQueryable<Entity> query = db.Entity;
  if (id != null)
    query = query.Where(p => p.Id == id);
  if (name != null)
    query = query.Where(p => p.Name == name);
  //else
  //  query = query.Where(p => p.Name != null);
  return query.Select(...).ToList();
}
```